# PHP mysql sort greatest to least

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I have a database table with a column labeled `earnings`. There are multiple users in this table who have a different amount of earnings. I want to display the top ten people with the most earnings.

This is the code that I currently have:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `earnings` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

How can I make it so that for instance if I write `$result['earnings'][3]` it'll give me the user with the fourth highest earnings. Or if I write `$result['user'][3]` it'll give me the username of the person with the fourth highest earnings?

Comment: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY earnings DESC limit 0,10")`

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: `$result` is a query result, not an array. You will need to load the result into an array before you can do anything with it. Also, `mysql_*()` are decade old, unsupported functions. Stop using them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to display the top ten people with the most earnings

Then add in your query `LIMIT 10`:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `earnings` DESC LIMIT 10") or die (mysql_error());
```

And also do not forget `mysql_*` is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use `mysqli_*` instead.

If you want to fetch, then use `while` cycle:

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  echo $result['username']; // write username, etc...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, however, how can I target, for instance, the user with the highest earnings, second highest, etc?

Comment: By using LIMIT. If you want second, you will use LIMIT 1,1. Which first 1 means it starts from 1. not 0. (0. is first, 1. second, 2. third, etc) and second 1 means how many results to display.